# Not able to run .NET MVC app. I have MS Visual Studio 2022 installed. All I get is an error, "Please select a valid statup item"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

[image]

Not able to run .NET MVC app. I have MS Visual Studio 2022 installed. All I get is an error, "Please select a valid statup item" when I click on the run button

Comment: Go on your `View` folder, select the `Index` view or the view that you want to show when your project loads. Right click on the `View` and click on `Set As Startup Page`. Once that is done, then choose the browser to open the project with by selecting from the dropdown where it say `Select startup item` in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't choose a starter project, you can choose one from the green colored button above.

Comment: Which green button?
The one that says "Select Startup Item" ?

Comment: Yes. This button. Or you could right click on the project file "BulkyWeb.csproj" and click on "Select as startup project"

Comment: When I click on that green button, I get the error that says "Please select a valid startup item"

Comment: When I right click on the file "BulkyWeb.csproj", I don't see an opiton for "Select as startup project".

Comment: you should be able to run your project with F5 from now on

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the project with the sln file.

```
File->Open->Project/Solution
```

The above answer would also help.

Comment: Already tried it. Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches

1. click triangle and select csproj file:

[image]

[image]

2.click sln file to switch to sln view:

[image]

Then click the triangle to select start project

[image]